# Any method for collect instance state changes in OCI with GO SDK

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-functions, oci-go-sdk, oracle-cloud-streaming

I want to aware if any instances changes state for example "up"->"down"
How to get this information with sdk ?
Any method for collecting that ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [GetInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/Instance/GetInstance) for that. It returns [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/iaas/20160918/Instance/) model, which has a "lifecycleState" field.

The first link also shows an example of how to call GetInstance from the Go SDK.

Comment: I Think
Event -> Streaming most convenient way.
I found in OCI documentation.